# Is there a way to get the url of popup js onclick dialogue using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

This is the website link which I am trying to scrape for data [https://tis.nhai.gov.in/tollplazasataglance.aspx?language=en#](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

There are links in 4th column in above site if clicked a popup window comes which has certain info along with href for the next link when we click More Information tab.We get to such links [https://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation.aspx?TollPlazaID=236](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

```
From selenium import webdriver

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://tis.nhai.gov.in/tollplazasataglance.aspx?language=en#")


b = driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="tollList"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/a')


c = driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", b)
```

At this point I am stuck up as am unable to capture the `href` or `url` of the popup window... Kindly help me to get past to the other page from the pop up window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those pop-ups are the result of POST requests, where the payload is each location ID. Here is a way to get the locations IDs:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time as t

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)
url = 'https://tis.nhai.gov.in/tollplazasataglance.aspx?language=en#'
driver.get(url)
places = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="tollList"]//tbody/tr/td[4]' )))
for p in places:
    p_id = p.find_element(By.XPATH, './/a').get_attribute('onclick').split('(')[1].split(')')[0]
    print(p.text, p_id)
```

Result in terminal:

```
Aganampudi 236
Amakathadu 258
Badava 4486
Bandapalli 5697
Bandlapalli 5952
Basapuram 4542
Bathalapalli 5753
Bolapalli 252
[...]
```

Once you have the IDs, you can go to each place' page with `https://tis.nhai.gov.in/TollInformation.aspx?TollPlazaID={place_id}`.

Comment: Thank you so much Barry, i could not find a way to retrieve the id's to loop thru each page.